# How to add a "plus" button on top of emptyView in ListView

Tags: android, listview, button

I'd like to add a `Button` like this one below into my `ListView` when the list is empty using the `setEmptyView()` method.

Is there a built-in style in Android for this? Because I noticed that a few apps are using exactly the same `Button` style.

Comment: That is a custom button, standard interface does not provide that style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No, this is not a standard `Button`.

However, you can add a similar `Button` by using an `ImageView`. You just have to design/download something you like.

Answer (score 6):

Look at this link: [Add Items to ListView - Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19468025/add-items-to-listview-android)

It shows the correct Android resource to use, which shows a green "+" symbol on the ImageButton.

To be precise:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/moreImageButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:contentDescription="@string/image_button_delete"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add" />
```