# Android: Updating List view or UI after executing asynctask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

My android application starts an activity which contains list view. Activity also contains one Button while pressing on it, it runs on asynctask and produce some result which should be updated(add one more item) to the list view. In my case the issue is asynctask produce the result but i don't no how to update my list view.
Also i don't want to use loading symbol.

Comment: are you getting response in post execute of asynctask

Comment: Yes,Post execute returns result.

Comment: then also add your code for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

In the **onPostExecute()** of your **AsyncTask** you should **add the new item to the List or ArrayList of your desired data** and then call the **listAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()** which will update the content of your listview.

Comment: if my asynctask is in separate class, how can I get notified by the post execute method to ui.

Comment: You better define it in the same class, where it should update the ui.

Answer (score 0):

Update your array list in onpostexecute() method. And then call notifydatasetchange method to update list.

For how to add check this- https://stackoverflow.com/a/19468504/2128166

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. When doInBackground() method return something, you have to override onPostExecuteMethod(). Inside this method you are on MainThread, so you can call for example:

```
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
     list.clear();
     list.addAll(result);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChaned();
}
```

Comment: clear() and allAll are only two method, maybe not necessary.